# Why does spellcheck="false" on textarea creates lags with caret?

Tags: html, reactjs

This problem is related to [that other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70066604/lags-in-caret-display-caret-does-not-reset-on-position-change/70095305#70095305) and its solution. So, basically, in my React app (I don't know if it's a global HTML issue), whenever I put spellCheck="false" on a textarea, the caret has display issues : when moved with keyboard arrows, its blinking cycle does not reset (which is the case when spellCheck is not specified). Even if I disable spellcheck directly from the browser, this problem appears.

So :

Is this a known issue ?

Is this a React thing or a global HTML issue ?

Is there a solution ?

Edit : This issue happens on Firefox but not on Brave. If I control this parameter with React like `spellCheck={checkSpell}`, for it to be true onKeyDown, then false onKeyUp, there's no problem anymore. But of course, the red wavy underlines blink like it's Christmas.

Comment: Which browsers are you experiencing this in and does it happen when not using React?

Comment: It's happening on Firefox, not on Brave @morganney
I would need to try without React.